# Scala xs.foreach(yield _)?

Tags: scala, foreach, yield

Learning about Scala and confused with the following:

Assume this: `val filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles`

This works: `for (fn <- filesHere) yield fn`

This works: `filesHere.foreach(println _)`

This doesn't work: `filesHere.foreach(yield _)`

The error message is: `<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression`

Why doesn't the last one work and how to get it to work using `foreach`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the files? If you're attempting to perform the same action on each file, a simple `map` would be a better choice. The `for(...) yield { ... }` syntax is sugar for a series of `flatMap` operations followed by one final `map` (the `yield`).

Here is a [link](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) to the documentation for further clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yield` is a keyword that is used only in combination with `for` comprehensions, i.e. `for (fn <- filesHere) yield fn` in your example code. This will iterate over `filesHere` and return each element via `yield fn`.

The following would then assign the resulting collection of `fn`elements to the value `result`:

```
val result = for (fn <- filesHere) yield fn
```

`for (fn <- filesHere) yield fn` is equivalent to `filesHere.map(fn => fn)`.

`filesHere.foreach(fn => fn)` would be equivalent to `for (fn <- filesHere) fn` (i.e. no `yield` keyword and thus no result element returned, which means it would in your case not do anything useful.

For completeness: `filesHere.foreach(println _)` is equivalent to `filesHere.foreach(fn => println(fn))` which does something more useful by printing to the standard output via `println`.

Hope this clarifies it a bit :).